# What is default username & password for a persistent pendrive?

Tags: password, default

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live CD asks for a username and password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password)

I am trying out Ubuntu 11.04 on a netbook.  I created a live USB to boot from using this:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

and the system boots up into Ubuntu from the USB stick, great!

bad news is I am presented with a login form.... I did not set a password so I have no idea what it could be....

username: other
password:

I have tried no password, no luck... I tried ubuntu, no luck

Any Ideas why it has a password, and what it might be or how I can set the password?