# LiveCD is asking for password after booting; default login details don't work

Tags: live-cd, password

The Ubuntu Live CD is asking for a password after booting in GDM. The username "ubuntu" and an empty password don't work. Normally the same CD never asked for a password. What is happening? What is the correct password? I badly need the live system!

Edit: none of the proposals at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/9193 worked.

Comment: Similar, but **not** a duplicate (since you said it didn't work): http://askubuntu.com/q/79774/18612

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/9193 (It isn't the wrong date and RAM seems to be okay too.)

Comment: If any of the suggestions in the linked question work for you (try the ones towards the bottom), be sure to post what worked as an answer below and accept it so we know it resolved your problem. Alternatively, if none of them work then edit your question to reflect that, as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if the CD is damaged, check the CD for scratches or dirt and then check the integrity of the CD.