# Incorrect Username/Password prompt on Ubuntu 12.04 Live USB

Tags: 12.04, login, live-usb, persistence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live CD asks for a username and password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password)

I'm having a little bit of trouble with Ubuntu12.04 on a Live USB.

Yesterday when installing mplayer 2 the system downloaded and installed an update into my live USB, after the update, mplayer2 opened and the system just froze, after about 10 minutes being frozen, I decided to make a hard reset (pressing the power button down), and after that the live USB just started to throw out I/O Errors When booting into the live session.

After 3 tries, the system booted normally but instead of taking me directly to the workspace, it showed a Login prompt, just to clarify I have NEVER made an account on the live USB, I just booted; I already tried typing "ubuntu" as Username and a blank password, but when I press enter the system just shows a black screen and some words (completely illegible, it just shows for half a second)and returns to the login screen, and everything else(like root and blank pwd) just gives me a "incorrect username/pwd" message.

I really need help with this, as I had some sensitive documents in my persistent Live session and can't afford to lose it (I don't have a backup, just yesterday those documents were finished and I don't have a HDD because it died and I'm using the live usb as a contingency plan until the new one arrives).

Comment: Please see this possible duplicate question [Live CD asks for a username and password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password)