# Can't startup as login screen requests a name and password - but I have not set one up yet?

Tags: 12.10, login, login-screen, versions

I am trying Ubuntu on an XP machine. Downloaded burnt to DVD - all good, rebooted and Ubuntu started from DVD. I clicked TRY and it then came up with a login.

What name and password do I use the first time?

Comment: Try "ubuntu" for username and a blank password. Also, see if this question helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password

Answer (score 0):

With **TRY** you are booting Ubuntu from the LiveCD.  The [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#Logging_in) site indicates, under the "Logging In" section:

> Sometimes a LiveCD might ask you for a user-name or password. Just leave these blank and press enter (or allow it to time-out).

Comment: thank youI tried just pressing enter but just remained status quo.

Comment: Can you confirm for us which exact version you downloaded?