# Login screen asking for credentials when I just booted into ubuntu for the first time off my thumb drive

Tags: 12.10

Ubuntu is asking for login credentials when I booted into it for the first time using a thumb drive, windows login not working.

Comment: I think this question is already answered in http://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password (if information from there doesn't help you, please provide more details)

Answer (score 0):

> ### try:
>
> - username: ubuntu
> - pass:  -blank-