# Authentication Failure Switch to greeter

Tags: login, 18.04, lightdm

I'm experiencing a very annoying problem on Ubuntu 18.04.

Whenever my laptop resumes after being suspended I'm completely unable to login and get the error;

```
Authentication Failure Switch to greeter
```

The issue is well described here, although it seems no one has found a solution to it.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1733557

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

**Update:**

To anyone who comes across this, the shortcut to get to the greeter without having to reboot is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Also if anyone of the people who voted to close this question had actually read the bug report above they'd see that users still report the same issue after upgrading to 18.04.

Comment: As long as you can access your account via `tty`, you can bypass it by this way: https://askubuntu.com/questions/557833/how-to-unlock-locked-session/611611#611611

Comment: Thanks. This at least saves me having to do a reboot every time which is awesome!

Comment: I'm hoping someone will post a permanent fix for this.

Comment: To anyone who comes across this, the shortcut to get to the greeter without having to reboot is Ctrl+Alt  f1

Comment: I would like to reopen and post that you can use ```$ sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm
$ sudo service lightdm restart```

Comment: @MichaelDurrant’s comment works according to [Angela’s bug report command](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1733557/comments/108).

Comment: @MichaelDurrant How to re-open this?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant The [post is open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040159/authentication-failure-switch-to-greeter#comment1769303_1040159) and awaiting your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per Michael Durrant's comment above and [this post](https://medium.com/@5XvYrLT7/fix-ubuntus-switch-to-greeter-bug-715d05520f46):

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm
$ sudo service lightdm restart
```

**Note**: Running this command will log you out of your system. So, make sure to save your work before that.

Comment: One time problem solved by reboot but then appears again. Suggested solution works for me.

Comment: WARNING: This works well. However, issuing these commands will log you out of the system. So, make sure to save your work before running these commands.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the issue by a simple restart.