# Unable to login to 15.04 with Live USB

Tags: login, 15.04

I am unable to login to Ubuntu 15.04 on my HP Pavilion dv7 laptop, which has an ATM Radeon graphics card, with the Live USB I just created. I was able to access the desktop using it with a Dell AlienWare laptop without being prompted for a login. I haven't created a login so I don't know why it's asking for one. Does anyone know how to disable the login prompt or at least setup a username/password so that I can access the desktop like I did on the other machine?

Comment: Why are you not installing? There should be no password

Comment: Well I just wanted to try it out first Tim. This is my first attempt at using Linux.

Comment: I see, I thought you were using it for a while. That's fine. Did it ever boot to the desktop?

Comment: It did on another laptop but it won't on this one.

Comment: Okay, http://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password may help?

Comment: I tried Ctrl Alt F1 at the login screen but nothing happened.

Comment: I tried pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 at the login screen (and I was able to create an account, with some difficulty) which appears to log me in when I'm in text mode. When I press Ctrl-Alt-F7 to get to the GUI I get the login prompt again, enter my password but it keeps going in a loop so I still can't login, any suggestions?