# 14.04 try Ubuntu asking for username and password

Tags: password

Hi I've seen this question but no answers
I've downloaded an ISO and burned a DVD and then booted from it, then it displays try Ubuntu and install Ubuntu I would like to try first but when I do this it asks for a username and password I haven't given one yet so I'm stuck, I would appreciate it someone could answer this, I'm not a complete beginner and have used unix in the past but new to Ubuntu
Regards Richard

Comment: Where did you download the ISO from? The official [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) website or another site?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying I downloaded it from http://www.ubuntu.com/download so I guess that's the official website

Comment: possible duplicate of [Live CD asks for a username and password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password)