# How to be root on liveUSB?

Tags: sudo, live-usb, root

As mentioned in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738107/sudo-command-not-working-in-live-usb) question, the `sudo` command in my live USB is not working. To fix this I need to run some commands. But every command I run says `permission denied`. How do I gain root access? Running `su -` asks for password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sudo command not working in live USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/738107/sudo-command-not-working-in-live-usb)

Comment: @DavidFoerster In that question, I ask about fixing the `sudo` command and here I want root access.

Comment: `sudo` gives you root access. If you get `sudo` to work, then you get root access. If you want to run a shell as super-user use `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 3):

As only the `sudo` command is not working because of a badly configured `/etc/sudoers` file, you can use `pkexec` as temporary replacement:

```
pkexec su -
```

`pkexec` will prompt a GUI password dialog every time you run it, it seems not to work in a TTY or when booting to text mode as it needs a dbus component.

You definitely need to fix your `/etc/sudoers` file, becoming lazy and just using `pkexec` from now on is not the way to go. That's not what it's made for.

Comment: In that case what would be the password? I was booting from a live USB.

Comment: The password should be empty, as you can read [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/103896/367990).

Comment: This is the login password. But when I ran `su -`, it asked for password and keeping it blank gives me "Authentication failure".

Comment: You may not run `su -`, that will ask you for the root account's password (which is deactivated). You must run `sudo su -` or in your case where `sudo` is broken `pkexec su -` to become root with your own account password.

Comment: Can't try it now. The pen drive is formatted. Thanks for the help though.