# Install Ubuntu on new Hardware

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I try to install Ubuntu and Mint on my PC, but no Version works :(

I put the OS on a USB-Stick and let them boot.
All i get is:

With SLI: Blackscreen after the Ubuntu-Logo. After a view seconds the Monitors goes off.

Without SLI:

- My Monitor goes off (Blackscreen)
- I come to a Login-Screen with Username and Password => I don't know any Password or Username

Mint can't run the "X Service". May by they haven't any graphics card driver on board.

I can't run the LIVE-System or install the OS.

I try it on follow System:

- MB: ASUS X99 Deluxe
- CPU: Intel i7 5930K
- RAM: 16GB DDR4
- GPU: 2x nVidia GeForce GTX 980 (SLI)
- 2 Monitors connected with Displayport or HDMI.

I think my hardware is not supported on Linux.

Someone know a fix for that?

Comment: Have you tried adding `nomodeset` to the boot options when you boot from the USB stick? You choose "custom options" (I think that's what it's called) at the boot screen by pressing F6, then add `nomodeset` to the end of them.

Comment: After a view tests, i know more.
My hardware is not supported.To be precise, my graphiccards are not supported.
If i install Ubuntu 14.04 it works fine. But only if i connect a monitor with HDMI or DVI. With Displayport i can only use a resolution of 800x600.
If i update to 16.04 i cant use the keyboard and mouse or any USB-Device.
Ubuntu laggs like hell and make some errors on the updateprocess.

Comment: Please have a look at the following Q&A and try again: [Live CD asks for a username and password](http://askubuntu.com/q/103896/40581)