# Ubuntu 16.04 login problem

Tags: 16.04, login, password, startup, usb-drive

I have problems with the startup from a USB flash. It asks for a login and a password and I don't know the login or password can anyone help? It writes `ubuntu 16.04 LTS ubuntu tty1` in a prompt.

Comment: Sounds a little bit strange. [See this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). Did you try root with empty passwd?

Comment: Try username: `ubuntu` with a blank password

Comment: Possibly related to this old question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password

Comment: empty Passwd? I just used the guide a the homepage for boot from a usb flash, and when i boot from it, it asks for a login :) and i didnt really get anything from the article but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Where did you get the installation ISO from?