# How do I log in to Ubuntu in "Install Ubuntu" mode?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 using an [ISO downloaded here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) and then creating a bootable USB using the [Universal USB Installer](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6153-universal-usb-installer.html) from my Windows 10 laptop. The bootable USB drive was created fine, when I rebooted I was presented with a choice to "Try Ubuntu without installing" and "Installing Ubuntu" (among others). Both these options boot Ubuntu and present a login screen - before any installer ever showed up, but I don't know how to log in here.

[The login screen that I saw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygANe.jpg)

My attempts so far (based on researching this site and others), none of which are successful:

- Tried username "ubuntu" with empty password, then "ubuntu" as password, then "password" as password"
- Tried empty username and password
- Tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. This switched to a command line, but the command line interface again asked for password.

Note: If you want to dupe this question to [Live CD asks for a username and password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password), please consider that I already tried the steps above (suggested in that question's answer) and I'm still unable to install.

Comment: Did you check all the answers? If you still have the ISO then try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/801438/248467

Comment: Have you tried with other USB installer? The official tutorial, [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) recommends to use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht thank you. your suggestion works