# What is the root login during installation?

Tags: system-installation, root, ubiquity

I need to troubleshoot my installation failure.
From the installer I can access the terminal using ALT + F2 but I still need user credentials.

Is there a default root login I can use during the installation?
I'm installing a custom ISO based on Ubuntu 19.10

So far I've tried:

- Username: root
- Password: root

---

- Username: ubuntu
- Password: ubuntu

---

- Username: root
- Password: ubuntu

---

- Username: root
- Password:

---

- Username: ubuntu
- Password:

Comment: Did you try `ubuntu` user with no password?

Comment: yeah no luck, i'll update the question with what I've tried

Comment: I thought that your question might be related to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password

Comment: There is no root login, but you should be able to use **`sudo` without any password** in a live session of Ubuntu and Ubuntu flavours.  **Login with user `ubuntu` without any password (only press the Enter key)**. If this does not work in your custom system, the system is different from Ubuntu and it is hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close reading of the question reveals that a customized disk, and not an original Ubuntu disk was in use.  Perhaps the reason the "ubuntu" login didn't work was because it was changed during customization (whether purposefully or inadvertently).  More than likely the actual details would have to come from the entity that produced the customized install media.

Regardless, for most cases of a question like this [FedonKadifeli's](https://askubuntu.com/users/855322/fedonkadifeli) suggested reference to [Live CD asks for a username and password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password) was good for 20.04.1 so unless 19.10 did something different, it should provide a satisfactory answer.  I referenced [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/103900/115439) answer, but [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/201931/115439) provides alternate usernames for various editions of Ubuntu.

It is possible to confirm during an Ubuntu 20.04.1 Desktop installation, while the installer is running, one may access an alternate virtual console with CTRL+ALT+Fn and login with username "ubuntu" and a null password.

```
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS ubuntu tty2

ubuntu login: ubuntu
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage


Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep install
ubuntu      1849    1566  0 20:19 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/busybox tail -f /var/log/installer/debug -f /var/log/syslog -q
...
```

A couple answers seem to indicate failures to get these logins work, but they have comments that either directly, or indirectly, dispute that they do not generally work.

As indicated by others, the login account does not have elevated (superuser) permissions, but `sudo` without a password is possible.

Comment: I don't have this environment to test any more but you're probably right, thanks for the help

Comment: Well, the answer might be generally correct, but as it is something you tried, and as it is something others suggested, it probably wasn't actually the answer. This answer is given mostly to help others. I found your question when looking for the password of an actual Ubuntu install disk. A close reading of your question reveals you weren't actually using an original Ubuntu disk, but rather a customized installer based on the Ubuntu disk. Perhaps that is the reason the "ubuntu" username didn't work; login details likely were changed during customization (whether purposefully or inadvertently).