# How do I ssh into the server installer

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, ssh

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/general) for a headless install.

I have placed the `ubuntu-21.04-live-server-amd64.iso` image on a USB key on a machine that has no keyboard/monitor/mouse. I observed that it successfully joined the network and SSH is running. However, I cannot `ssh` into the installer. I have tried `ubuntu:ubuntu` and `root:ubuntu`, but both are not accepted. I have also tried `ubuntu:` (no password) per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/103896/1165986) with no success. I also tried `root:` without a password and it is not accepted.

The instructions say:

> If the only available terminal is very basic, an alternative is to connect via SSH. If the network is up by the time the installer starts, instructions are offered on the initial screen in basic mode. Otherwise, instructions are available from the help menu once networking is configured.

What are the instructions? What is the default username and password for the installer?

Comment: How do you want to `ssh` "into the installer"? I think you want to `ssh` into the machine with the USB stick and then start the installer, right?

Comment: Per Ubuntu's docs, the new installer starts an sshd instance when you boot from the install media. This is supposed to let you SSH into the machine as it's running the install environment. However, they are not at all clear what password you're supposed to use.

Comment: I did this yesterday on 22.04.xx Server.  The UART console installer told me the ssh credentials, which unfortunately included a long random password.  Nothing obvious like `admin` or `ubuntu`, etc.  I then ssh'd in and it gave me a nice color installer.  In this case I had TTY connected (FTDI cable), so I don't think this addresses the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

the help menu is in the top right as have the installer open

in the orange bar, you can just press up until you reach it

[picture of ubuntu installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSe4n.png) (don't have the rep to post images)

also there is the next section, just after the one you quoted:

> ### Help menu
>
> The help menu is always in the top right of the screen. It contains help, both general and for the currently displayed screen, and some general actions.

Comment: how do you suppose to view this help when you cannot ssh into the system and there's no console attached to it? somehow, your answer doesn't make sense.