# What exactly do I need to input when a command asks for my user in this format: '<your user>:<your user>'

Tags: command-line, live-usb

I'm using a live usb version of Ubuntu while attempting to the instructions outlined in the documentation of Windows 10 AME and am stuck here. The full command is:

```
sudo chown <your user>:<your user> /media/ntfs
```

I've tried inputting what's shown at the top of the terminal window `ubuntu@ubuntu:~` but I get 'invalid user' in response.

https://wiki.ameliorated.info/doku.php?id=documentation_21h1

Comment: It should be `ubuntu:ubuntu`, if that is the username.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Now I have to figure out why the heck I'm getting a "unknown filesystem type 'ufsd'." error after hitting the penultimate step in the process. It happens after inputting: 'sudo mount -t ufsd -w /dev/sbd3 /media/ntfs'  with sbd3 being my windows 10 location. I guess I have to create a new question officially for this one?

Comment: You probably don’t need the -t ufsd option. ufsd is a driver for NTFS drives. If you haven’t got it installed then it definitely will not work. I think it’s redundant now because depending on your kernel it’s become unnecessary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live CD asks for a username and password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password)