# forgot ubuntu password of instance

Tags: server, 20.04, login, password, oracle

i have an oracle instance with ubuntu i don't remember having set a password for ubuntu but when i run the following command

```
systemctl enable emperor.uwsgi.service
```

it's required a password

```
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:
```

now i don't understand what's this password came from i have tried the password of oracle cloud account and other possible password there is a way to avoid this password when i run this command or find my password

Comment: The default should be no password, or 'ubuntu' - it depends on how the system was deployed and set up by the provider.  Since Oracle deployed the instance, Oracle might have a specific way for you to login (they may have set up `root` or such with a password that's accessible in their cloud panel).  NOTICE though: you tagged this as 14.04.  Ubuntu 14.04 is long past end of standard support and not supported here, if you're using 14.04 upgrade to 20.04 or 22.04 for continued support here.

Comment: the password could be my private or public `SSH` key?

Comment: No, a password is NOT an SSH key.  They would have set the password as a legitimate password if they gave the `ubuntu` user sudoer access.  You need to search Oracle Cloud's documentation for how they configure default accounts on their images, most of the time `ubuntu` is not set with a password at all for use, and sometimes they're created with the default password I stated, and sometimes a randomly generated password you can only find in the control panel on the Oracle Cloud side of things

Comment: ok thank you, and what's the question  i have to search in the documentation: a thing just like "password ubuntu"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live CD asks for a username and password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password)

Comment: yes problem solved